# Why am I getting "name is not defined" error message?

Tags: python, function

I am taking online course on Python Functions.  I am getting an NameError as shown below.  Can someone figure out why I am getting such error?

```
def student_details (**details_dictionary): 
    if 'name' in details : 
        print ("Name:", details['name'] ) 
    if 'age' in details : 
        print ("Age:", details['age'] ) 
    if 'college' in details : 
        print ("College:", details['college'] )

student_details(name="John")
```

---

```
 NameError Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-24-9617ce938851> in <module>
 ----> 1 student_details(name="John")

 <ipython-input-23-1424bf8f28d7> in
 student_details(**details_dictionary)
       1 def student_details (**details_dictionary):
 ----> 2     if 'name' in details :
       3         print ("Name:", details['name'] )
       4     if 'age' in details :
       5         print ("Age:", details['age'] )

NameError: name 'details' is not defined
```

Comment: because indeed what is `details`? replace `details_dictionary` with `details`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to change `details` with `details_dictionary`

Comment: Replacing details_dictionary to details worked! It is still puzzling though I was following online training presentation exactly the same.  It worked in the presentation but mine did not.  Thanks you all!

Answer (score 1):

```
def student_details (**details_dictionary):
```

Here you name the parameter `details_dictionary`

```
    if 'name' in details : 
        print ("Name:", details['name'] )
```

Then here you try to use something named `details`. These names should be the same. I suggest you change the former to just `details`. You should generally avoid using words like `dictionary` or `list` that describe the kind of data structure in your variable name. If you come back and change the dictionary to a list, for example, then you have to track down the variable names to change them, too. You can avoid this extra work by leaving that detail out of your variable name.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any variable or reference named `details`. Change `details` to `details_dictionary` or change your parameter name to correspond to `details`